# Details of .NET/C# thread "termination" in COM context

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, com

I have been battling with Apartment State and COM in C# for a while now and finally got to an understanding of how the c#/.net thread´s apartment state affects COM. My problem has been that I require my COM object to make use of an MTA apartment, and in the past I have been trying to achieve this either by changing the apartment state of the existing thread (that does NOT work :) ) or making calls to the COM object from a new thread created with the MTA apartment state. However, I finally figured out that the determining factor is the apartment state of the thread on which the COM object is created.

To make sure my COM object is actually created in an MTA apartment I am using the following "hack":

```
        Thread thread =
                new Thread(
                    () => comObject = CreateCOMObject(className));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
```

Doing this it seems that my COM object is nicely created in an MTA apartment on the newly created MTA thread. 
So my question is how the thread lifetime and the COM object lifetime affects each other. I have the thread.Join in there to make sure the COM object is created before continueing, but wouldn't that imply the thread terminated and in that case on what thread is the COM object running after it is created? Is the COM object created in thread local storage or in the main application memory or in a new thread created by COM?
Note that this is In-process COM, not a COM server - so I guess it creates an AppDomain within the existing application and starts a totally new thread and creates the COM object in this context?

My above solution seems to work just fine, I was just wondering about the details to avoid potential issues in production.

So, to summarize, my question is whether this is a safe way of making sure my COM objects are created using MTA apartments and also whether there is any risk that the object memory will be garbage collected or something and cause strange behaviour I am not noticing while debugging. I do keep a reference to the comObject that is created inside the thread, so I guess there should be no reason for it to get garbage collected.

Comment: You don't make it easy to answer this question. There is a crucial detail missing, the COM component's ThreadingModel registry key matters a lot.  If you have no idea then at least explain why you are doing this.  Describe what happens when you create the object normally, without using a thread.

Comment: The COM component uses Both as the ThreadingModel. If I create the object normally, all calls made to the thread in a WPF application is made on an STA apartment independent of the calling method's thread's apartment state.

Comment: Then there is no concern, other than some discomfort about the author actually testing it.  I suppose you did this because you noticed that the object was eating too much time on the UI thread and affecting the responsiveness of the UI (don't make us guess).   Not exactly a ringing endorsement.  A .NET program always has a thread in the MTA so the object cannot die unexpectedly.

Comment: Since I use my own synchronization between objects shared between the threads the additional synchronization imposed by the STA apartment results in deadlocks.
I presume I am answering my own question - since the ThreadingModel is Both it takes the model of the creating thread, if the ThreadingModel was set to MTA it would create an MTA apartment even when created on STA thread?

Comment: When it is Both then COM assumes that the object is thread-safe and calls don't have to marshaled when it is created on an MTA thread.  That normally *increases* the odds for deadlock since you can only ever write thread-safe code with locks.  If ThreadingModel = Apartment then no locking is required at all, COM ensures that calls are always made on the thread that created the object.  Even if you create it on an MTA thread, COM will then create an STA thread to keep the object safe.